# networkx:creating a subgraph induced from edges

Tags: python, graph, networkx

networkx only has a function

> Graph.subgraph()

to create a subgraph induced from nodes.
but how to construct a subgraph from edge list ?

thanks !

Comment: Do you care whether the graph actually points to the original object (so that the edges carry references to the edges of the original graph)? The way that they describe below is effectively equivalent (for an original graph of type `nx.Graph` `G`) `G.subgraph(nbunch).copy()` (see https://networkx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.subgraph.html#networkx.Graph.subgraph). If you want to do this in a way keeps the reference, I think you'll need a different approach. I may need to do this, I'll post an answer if I solve it.

Comment: I see a [Graph.edge_subgraph](https://networkx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.edge_subgraph.html#networkx.Graph.edge_subgraph) method, but it doesn't appear to be available in the version of networkx that I have (1.10).

Comment: @dbw It must have been implemented recently, and I like a lot of how it is implemented. Not sure I like that you have separately declare a copy rather than passing an argument, but it probably makes sense for API consistency.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a list of edges, then you already have the subgraph. Just call `nx.Graph` on the list, and optionally add the (unconnected) nodes from the original graph. From the [docs](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.__init__.html#networkx.Graph.__init__)

```
Graph.__init__(data=None, **attr)
```

> Initialize a graph with edges, name, graph attributes.
>   Data to initialize graph. If data=None (default) an empty graph is created. The data can be an **edge list**, or any NetworkX graph object.

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I improved your answer by adding a link to the docs and some more helpful information from the page.

Comment: I already have a graph g,and I want to creat a subgraph based partial edges. igraph package has the related function, but it seems networkx could only build a subgraph induced from nodes

Comment: @user2281114: that's because *you don't need* a function for that. You can just construct a new graph from that list of edges and it'll be exactly the subgraph you want.

Comment: This drops node and edge attributes.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @larsmans is correct.  Here is a simple example:

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G = nx.path_graph(6)

In [3]: G.edges()
Out[3]: [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]

In [4]: subgraph_edges = [(1,2), (3,4)]

In [5]: S = nx.Graph(subgraph_edges)

In [6]: S.edges()
Out[6]: [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
```

Comment: this works well on networkx,thanks! igraph must receive continuos number，so I confuse two issues.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a function that has the properties that `Graph.subgraph()` has for subgraphs created from nodes but instead this function works on iterators of edges, you need to keep references to the original graph, edges and nodes to be able to propagate changes in the graph, edge or node data attributes. Notably from the docstring of `Graph.subgraph()`:

> The graph, edge or node attributes just point to the original graph.
>   So changes to the node or edge structure will not be reflected in the
>   original graph while changes to the attributes will.
>
> To create a subgraph with its own copy of the edge/node attributes
>   use: nx.Graph(G.subgraph(nbunch))
>
> If edge attributes are containers, a deep copy can be obtained using:
>   G.subgraph(nbunch).copy()

The currently proposed methods will not reflect changes in their attributes back in the original graph, as they will create a new graph from scratch.

There is no built in function/method for accomplishing this with a list of edges. But this function uses the infrastructure of the node `.subgraph` and thus should work for Graph and DiGraph. It will not work for not MultiGraph and MultiDiGraph. This is because MultiGraph and MultiDiGraph may need you to refer to the key of the edge and the current approach ignores arguments after the second so as to be insensitive to whether the passed in list of edges has attributes attached as a dictionary or not. Also, even when it is created without reference (by passing `ref_back=False`), it does not create a new graph using the `nx.Graph` or `nx.DiGraph` class initializers, but a deepcopy of the original graph. It would be possible to extend it to cover other cases… but I don't need that for now, and until someone explicitly asks for it I'm going to assume that no one else does (see [github](https://github.com/michaelpacer/hidden_structure_inference/blob/master/lib/subgraph_functions.py#L5) if you want to see the version that I've used in practice).

```
def subgraph_from_edges(G,edge_list,ref_back=True):
    """
    Creates a networkx graph that is a subgraph of G
    defined by the list of edges in edge_list.        

    Requires G to be a networkx Graph or DiGraph
    edge_list is a list of edges in either (u,v) or (u,v,d) form
    where u and v are nodes comprising an edge, 
    and d would be a dictionary of edge attributes

    ref_back determines whether the created subgraph refers to back
    to the original graph and therefore changes to the subgraph's 
    attributes also affect the original graph, or if it is to create a
    new copy of the original graph. 
    """

    sub_nodes = list({y for x in edge_list for y in x[0:2]})
    edge_list_no_data = [edge[0:2] for edge in edge_list]
    assert all([e in G.edges() for e in edge_list_no_data])

    if ref_back:
        G_sub = G.subgraph(sub_nodes)
        for edge in G_sub.edges():
            if edge not in edge_list_no_data:
                G_sub.remove_edge(*edge)
    else:
        G_sub = G.subgraph(sub_nodes).copy()
        for edge in G_sub.edges():
            if edge not in edge_list_no_data:
                G_sub.remove_edge(*edge)

    return G_sub
```

The trick is that any nodes not present in the edges can be safely excised from the graph (giving us our node subset), and then you can remove any edges that remain but aren't in your edge list.

Note: I realize that this is now a fairly ancient question, but the answers provided don't actually answer the question if interpreted as a case where the asker wanted a graph that directly referenced the original graph, edges and nodes (notably including their data attributes). I needed that solution, so I figured I'd post it regardless.

Comment: Realizing this is an old post, but I am looking for this functionality with a MultiDiGraph

Comment: Not too old compared to some I've tried to revive :). And I can't write something for a MultiDiGraph right now, but the trick is going to be to store the key of each edge you would like to keep. The line that will likely have to be deleted is `edge_list_no_data = [edge[0:2] for edge in edge_list]` and `for edge in G_sub.edges():` will need to be changed to something like  `for edge in G_sub.edges(keys=True):` but then you'll need to make sure that `edge_list_no_data` does have keys for the other lines to work.

Comment: Although old, I paste some advice here in case someone needs. For non bi-direction graph, "edge in edge_list_no_data" is better changed to be "(u,v) in edge_list_no_data or (v,u) in edge_list_no_data" or "G.has_edge(u,v)" because of the possible issues caused by the order of nodes in edges. If we only need the attributes from edges,the function can be easily written as "G_sub = networkx.Graph([(u, v, d) for u, v, d in G.edges(data=True) if ((u, v) in edge_list) or ((v, u) in edge_list)])".

Comment: @Young I was making the assumption that if you had a non-bidirectional graph that you were being careful about which of the edges you would want to keep. And non-bidirectional graphs are actually exactly the use-case I wrote this for. There are cases where you have a graph with 2-node cycles and want to only return graphs without cycles. In that case, your one-liner would not be able to remove one direction of the edges while leaving the other. Also, it would either not be able to refer back the original graph or not be able to make a new copy. I think the first one, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

As per [dbn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1309332/dbn)'s comment, networkx now includes a function [`nx.edge_subgraph`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.edge_subgraph.html) to do this. It preserves the attributes from the original graph, however changes to these attributes will be reflected in the original graph.

```
G = nx.path_graph(5)
S = G.edge_subgraph([(0, 1), (3, 4)])
list(S.nodes) # [0, 1, 3, 4]
list(H.edges) # [(0, 1), (3, 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Building up on the previous answers, a really simple workaround to retain the original graph with all its attributes might be this:

```
FG = nx.Graph(fedges)
G = G.subgraph(FG.nodes())
```

Here, *fedges* is the list of filtered edges to build the subgraph. First, create a new temporary graph (*FG*) with the filtered edges. Then use the node list (*FG.nodes()*) to get a subgraph from the original graph.  Since, you are actually using the *subgraph* function on the original graph object, you're not going to loose any attributes from it.